# Pandas: Column value assignment in function not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
country | year      | supporting_nation | eco_sup  | mil_sup
------------------------------------------------------------------
  Fake       1984        US                 1          1
  Fake       1984        SU                 0          1
```

In this fake example, a nation is playing both sides during the cold war and receiving support from both.

I am reshaping the dataset in two ways:

1. I removed all non US / SU instances of support, I am only interested in these two countries
2. I want to reduce it to `1 line per year per country`, meaning that I am adding US / SU specific dummy variables for each variable

Like so:

```
country |   year      | US_SUP | US_eco_sup  | US_mil_sup | SU_SUP | SU_eco_sup  | SU_mil_sup |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Fake       1984        1             1          1         1          1             1
 Fake       1985        1             1          1         1          1             1
 florp      1984        0             0          0         1          1             1
 florp      1985        0             0          0         1          1             1
```

I added all of the dummies and the `US_SUP` and `SU_SUP` columns have been populated with the correct values.

However, I am having trouble with giving the right value to the other variables.

To do so, I wrote the following function:

```
def get_values(x):
    cols = ['eco_sup', 'mil_sup']
    nation = ''
    if x['SU_SUP'] == 1:
        nation = 'SU_'
    if x['US_SUP'] == 1:
        nation = 'US_'

    support_vars = x[['eco_sup', 'mil_sup']]
    # Since each line contains only one measure of support I can
    # automatically assume that the support_vars are from
    # the correct nation
    support_cols = [nation + x for x in cols]
    x[support_cols] = support_vars
```

The plan is than to use a `df.groupby.agg('max')` operation, but I never get to this step as the function above return `0` for each new dummy col, regardless of the value of the columns in the dataframe.

So in the last table all of the `US/SU_mil/eco_sup` variables would be 0.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong / why the columns are getting the wrong value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by abandoning the `.apply` function and using this instead (where `old` is a list of the old variable names)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['SU_SUP'] == 1:
        nation = 'SU_'
        for col in old:
            df[index: index + 1][nation + col] = int(row[col])
    if row['US_SUP'] == 1:
        nation = 'US_'
        for col in old:
            df[index: index + 1][nation + col] = int(row[col])
```

This did the trick!

Comment: It would be great to know why you couldn't `.apply` here.  Its quite a useful pattern and bugs like these are very frustrating.